# Convert UCS-2 file to UTF-8 with PHP

Tags: php, encoding

I have a CSV file supplied from a client which has to be parsed and inserted into a database using PHP.

Before inserting the data into the DB, I want to convert it to UTF-8 but I cant seem to find how.

This is what I got trying to detect the files encoding:

```
$ enca -d -L zh ./artigos.txt 
    ./artigos.txt: Universal character set 2 bytes; UCS-2; BMP
    CRLF line terminators
    Byte order reversed in pairs (1,2 -> 2,1)
```

I tried using the iconv function but it messes up the conversion and shows the result with diferent characters than the originals.

First line of the file (base64 encoded):

```
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
```

Comment: extract a sample of text, in particular a small chunk surrounding the characters that get messed up in conversion. Transport them to us binary safe via [base64_encode](http://www.php.net/base64_encode)(). Then maybe someone can identify it. I'm guessing it might be big endian?

Comment: Added the first line of the file to the original post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work(little endian), althoug you didnt include any non ascii chars

```
$s='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';
$t=base64_decode($s);
echo iconv('UCS-2LE', 'UTF-8', substr($t, 0, -1));//last byte was invalid
```

Comment: That did it, thanks. I was using 'UCS-2' instead of 'UCS-2LE' before, and I wasn't trimming the last byte either.

Answer (score 8):

Microsoft Excel CSV are generally Little Endian encoded (took me long to find out).
If you want to use them with `fgetcsv` or similar functions, you should convert the file into UTF-8 first.

I do the following:

```
$str = file_get_contents($file);
$str = mb_convert_encoding($str, 'UTF-8', 'UCS-2LE'); 
file_put_contents("converted_".$file, $str);
```

Comment: Works for me with encoding 'UCS-2'.

Answer (score 0):

## python :

One of the method to encode is

> Text -> utf-16-be -> hexadecimal

Convert back

> hexadecimal to binary and then from utf-16-be to text

Note : ucs-2be is deprecated and move to utf-16-be

Decoder

```
import binascii
code = '098 ... '
decoded_text = binascii.unhexlify(code).decode('utf-16-be')
```