# ORA-22927: invalid LOB locator specified

Tags: java, plsql, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have the plsql code to update a file content in blob into a table as below,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY XXTXB_UPLOAD_FILE_PKG AS
PROCEDURE FILE_UPLOAD(P_FILE_NAME IN VARCHAR2,P_FILE_CONTENT IN BLOB) AS
GN_USER_ID       NUMBER:= APPS.FND_GLOBAL.USER_ID;
GN_LOGIN_ID      NUMBER:= APPS.FND_GLOBAL.LOGIN_ID;
LV_SEQ_NUM NUMBER:=XXTXB_UPLOAD_STG_S.NEXTVAL;
LV_FILE_NAME VARCHAR(500);
LV_FILE_PATH VARCHAR2(500):='/u01/Jdevloper/xxtxb';
LV_FILE      UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
LV_BUFFER    RAW(32767);
LV_AMOUNT    BINARY_INTEGER := 32767;
LV_POS       INTEGER := 1;
LV_BLOB_LEN  INTEGER;
LV_USER_NAME VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
--Getting user name
SELECT USER_NAME INTO LV_USER_NAME FROM FND_USER WHERE USER_ID=GN_USER_ID;
--Server File Name
SELECT 
TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'yyyymmddhh24miss')||'_'||LV_USER_NAME||'_'||P_FILE_NAME 
INTO LV_FILE_NAME FROM DUAL;
--Inserting into the staging table about the details
INSERT INTO XXTXB_UPLOAD_STG
VALUES (LV_SEQ_NUM,GN_USER_ID,
        P_FILE_NAME,
        LV_FILE_NAME,
        P_FILE_CONTENT,
        LV_FILE_PATH,
        SYSDATE,
        GN_USER_ID,
        SYSDATE,
        GN_USER_ID,
        GN_LOGIN_ID);
COMMIT;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('TABLE UPDATED SUCESSFULLY');
--Length of the file 
LV_BLOB_LEN := DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(P_FILE_CONTENT);
--Opeing the file
LV_FILE := UTL_FILE.FOPEN(LV_FILE_PATH,LV_FILE_NAME,'wb', 32767);
--Writing into the file
WHILE LV_POS < LV_BLOB_LEN LOOP
DBMS_LOB.READ(P_FILE_CONTENT, LV_AMOUNT, LV_POS, LV_BUFFER);
UTL_FILE.PUT_RAW(LV_FILE, LV_BUFFER, TRUE);
LV_POS := LV_POS + LV_AMOUNT;
END LOOP;  
--Closing the file
UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(LV_FILE);
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
IF UTL_FILE.IS_OPEN(LV_FILE) THEN
UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(LV_FILE);
END IF;
RAISE;
END FILE_UPLOAD;
END XXTXB_UPLOAD_FILE_PKG;
/
```

I'm calling this procedure in OAF in Impl code as follows:

```
public void WriteToServer(String P_FILE_NAME,String s) throws   
SerialException,SQLException
{  
byte[] buff = s.getBytes();
BLOB P_FILE_CONTENT=new BLOBChild();    
P_FILE_CONTENT.setBytes(buff);      
OADBTransaction oadbtransaction = (OADBTransaction)getTransaction();
OADBTransactionImpl oadbtransactionimpl = 
(OADBTransactionImpl)getTransaction();
  StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer();
  str.append( " BEGIN ");
  str.append( " XXTXB_UPLOAD_FILE_PKG.FILE_UPLOAD( ");
  str.append( " P_FILE_NAME=>:1,");
  str.append( " P_FILE_CONTENT=>:2");
  str.append( " ); ");
  str.append( " END; ");    
OracleCallableStatement oraclecallablestatement =(OracleCallableStatement)
oadbtransaction.createCallableStatement(str.toString(),1);
 try
 {
   oraclecallablestatement.setString(1, P_FILE_NAME);      
   oraclecallablestatement.setBLOB(2, P_FILE_CONTENT);      
   oraclecallablestatement.execute(); 
 }
 catch(Exception e)
 {
  throw OAException.wrapperException(e);
 } 
 }
```

When I try to update the file to the server using OAF I'm facing the following error,

```
oracle.apps.fnd.framework.OAException: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-22927: 
invalid LOB locator specified

at oracle.apps.fnd.framework.OAException.wrapperInvocationTargetException(Unknown Source)
at oracle.apps.fnd.framework.server.OAUtility.invokeMethod(Unknown Source)
at oracle.apps.fnd.framework.server.OAUtility.invokeMethod(Unknown Source)
at oracle.apps.fnd.framework.server.OAApplicationModuleImpl.invokeMethod(Unknown Source)
at xxtxb.oracle.apps.fnd.FileUpload.webui.FileUploadCO.processFormRequest(FileUploadCO.java:73)
at oracle.apps.fnd.framework.webui.OAWebBeanHelper.processFormRequest(Unknown Source)
at oracle.apps.fnd.framework.webui.OAWebBeanContainerHelper.processFormRequest(Unknown Source)
at oracle.apps.fnd.framework.webui.OAPageLayoutHelper.processFormRequest(Unknown Source)
at oracle.apps.fnd.framework.webui.beans.layout.OAPageLayoutBean.processFormRequest(Unknown Source)
at oracle.apps.fnd.framework.webui.OAWebBeanHelper.processFormRequestChildren(Unknown Source)
at oracle.apps.fnd.framework.webui.OAWebBeanHelper.processFormRequestChildren(Unknown Source)
at oracle.apps.fnd.framework.webui.OAWebBeanHelper.processFormRequest(Unknown Source)
at oracle.apps.fnd.framework.webui.OAWebBeanContainerHelper.processFormRequest(Unknown Source)
at oracle.apps.fnd.framework.webui.beans.form.OAFormBean.processFormRequest(Unknown Source)
at oracle.apps.fnd.framework.webui.OAWebBeanHelper.processFormRequestChildren(Unknown Source)
at oracle.apps.fnd.framework.webui.OAWebBeanHelper.processFormRequestChildren(Unknown Source)
at oracle.apps.fnd.framework.webui.OAWebBeanHelper.processFormRequest(Unknown Source)
at oracle.apps.fnd.framework.webui.OAWebBeanContainerHelper.processFormRequest(Unknown Source)
at oracle.apps.fnd.framework.webui.beans.OABodyBean.processFormRequest(Unknown Source)
at oracle.apps.fnd.framework.webui.OAPageBean.processFormRequest(Unknown Source)
at oracle.apps.fnd.framework.webui.OAPageBean.preparePage(Unknown Source)
at oracle.apps.fnd.framework.webui.OAPageBean.preparePage(Unknown Source)
at oracle.apps.fnd.framework.webui.OAPageBean.preparePage(Unknown Source)
at _OA._jspService(_OA.java:75)
at com.orionserver.http.OrionHttpJspPage.service(OrionHttpJspPage.java:59)
at oracle.jsp.runtimev2.JspPageTable.service(JspPageTable.java:473)
at oracle.jsp.runtimev2.JspServlet.internalService(JspServlet.java:594)
at oracle.jsp.runtimev2.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:518)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)
at com.evermind.server.http.ServletRequestDispatcher.invoke(ServletRequestDispatcher.java:734)
at com.evermind.server.http.ServletRequestDispatcher.forwardInternal(ServletRequestDispatcher.java:391)
at com.evermind.server.http.HttpRequestHandler.doProcessRequest(HttpRequestHandler.java:908)
at com.evermind.server.http.HttpRequestHandler.processRequest(HttpRequestHandler.java:458)
at com.evermind.server.http.HttpRequestHandler.serveOneRequest(HttpRequestHandler.java:226)
at com.evermind.server.http.HttpRequestHandler.run(HttpRequestHandler.java:127)
at com.evermind.server.http.HttpRequestHandler.run(HttpRequestHandler.java:116)
at oracle.oc4j.network.ServerSocketReadHandler$SafeRunnable.run(ServerSocketReadHandler.java:260)
at oracle.oc4j.network.ServerSocketAcceptHandler.procClientSocket(ServerSocketAcceptHandler.java:234)
at oracle.oc4j.network.ServerSocketAcceptHandler.access$700(ServerSocketAcceptHandler.java:29)
at oracle.oc4j.network.ServerSocketAcceptHandler$AcceptHandlerHorse.run(ServerSocketAcceptHandler.java:879)
at com.evermind.util.ReleasableResourcePooledExecutor$MyWorker.run(ReleasableResourcePooledExecutor.java:303)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

and the corresponding table is,

```
CREATE TABLE xxtxb_upload_stg
(
  file_id           NUMBER        NOT NULL,
  uploaded_by       NUMBER        NOT NULL,
  upload_file_name  VARCHAR2(300) NOT NULL,
  server_file_name  VARCHAR2(300) NOT NULL,
  file_content      BLOB,
  file_path         VARCHAR2(500),
  -- --------------------
  -- Who Columns
  -- --------------------
  last_update_date   DATE     NOT NULL,
  last_updated_by    NUMBER   NOT NULL,
  creation_date      DATE     NOT NULL,
  created_by         NUMBER   NOT NULL,
  last_update_login  NUMBER 
 );
```

Controller Code:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import oracle.apps.fnd.common.VersionInfo;
import oracle.apps.fnd.framework.webui.OAControllerImpl;
import oracle.apps.fnd.framework.webui.OAPageContext;
import oracle.apps.fnd.framework.webui.beans.OAWebBean;
import oracle.cabo.ui.data.DataObject;
import java.io.InputStream;
import oracle.jbo.domain.BlobDomain;
import oracle.apps.fnd.framework.OAException;
import oracle.apps.fnd.framework.OAApplicationModule;
import java.io.Serializable;
public class FileUploadCO extends OAControllerImpl
{
 BlobDomain uploadedByteStream=new BlobDomain(); ;
 String P_FILE_NAME="";
 String s=new String();
 public static final String RCS_ID="$Header$";
 public static final boolean RCS_ID_RECORDED =
 VersionInfo.recordClassVersion(RCS_ID, "%packagename%");
 public void processRequest(OAPageContext pageContext, OAWebBean webBean)
{
 super.processRequest(pageContext, webBean);
}
public void processFormRequest(OAPageContext pageContext, OAWebBean webBean)
{ 
super.processFormRequest(pageContext, webBean);  

if(pageContext.getParameter("Submit")!=null)
{

 upLoadFile(pageContext,webBean);   


  OAApplicationModule am = pageContext.getApplicationModule(webBean);
  Serializable[] parameters1 = {P_FILE_NAME,s};
  am.invokeMethod("WriteToServer", parameters1);
}
}
public void upLoadFile(OAPageContext pageContext,OAWebBean webBean)
{ 
String fileUrl = null;
try
{
 System.out.println("URL---->"+fileUrl);
 DataObject fileUploadData =  
 pageContext.getNamedDataObject("MessageFileUpload");
 if(fileUploadData!=null)
 {

 P_FILE_NAME = (String)fileUploadData.selectValue(null, "UPLOAD_FILE_NAME"); 
 String contentType = (String) 
 fileUploadData.selectValue(null,"UPLOAD_FILE_MIME_TYPE");  
 System.out.println("User File Name---->"+P_FILE_NAME);

 InputStream input = null;

 uploadedByteStream = (BlobDomain)fileUploadData.selectValue(null, 
 P_FILE_NAME);

 input = uploadedByteStream.getInputStream();
  byte[] contents;
  ByteArrayOutputStream byteoutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
  int count;
  while ((count = input.read(buffer)) != -1){byteoutput.write(buffer, 0, 
  count);}//debugger says myinputstream has blksize 16384, buffcount 12742, 
  and max 127394 here
  contents = byteoutput.toByteArray();
  s=contents.toString();

  input.close();
  }
 }
 catch(Exception ex)
 {
  throw new OAException(ex.getMessage(), OAException.ERROR);
 }   

 }
```

}

Could anyone help me on this....

After completing the SQL session error as suggested now I get this conversion error.

```
Exception Details.  
oracle.apps.fnd.framework.OAException: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00603: 
ORACLE server session terminated by fatal error
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [kghfrmrg:nxt], [0x7F069D63B360], 
[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
ORA-24812: character set conversion to or from UCS2 failed
ORA-06512: at "APPS.XXTXB_UPLOAD_FILE_PKG", line 68
ORA-06512: at line 1

at oracle.apps.fnd.framework.OAException.wrapperInvocationTargetException(Unknown Source)
at oracle.apps.fnd.framework.server.OAUtility.invokeMethod(Unknown Source)
at oracle.apps.fnd.framework.server.OAUtility.invokeMethod(Unknown Source)
at oracle.apps.fnd.framework.server.OAApplicationModuleImpl.invokeMethod(Unknown Source)
at xxtxb.oracle.apps.fnd.FileUpload.webui.FileUploadCO.processFormRequest(FileUploadCO.java:73)
at oracle.apps.fnd.framework.webui.OAWebBeanHelper.processFormRequest(Unknown Source)
at oracle.apps.fnd.framework.webui.OAWebBeanContainerHelper.processFormRequest(Unknown Source)
at oracle.apps.fnd.framework.webui.OAPageLayoutHelper.processFormRequest(Unknown Source)
at oracle.apps.fnd.framework.webui.beans.layout.OAPageLayoutBean.processFormRequest(Unknown Source)
at oracle.apps.fnd.framework.webui.OAWebBeanHelper.processFormRequestChildren(Unknown Source)
at oracle.apps.fnd.framework.webui.OAWebBeanHelper.processFormRequestChildren(Unknown Source)
at oracle.apps.fnd.framework.webui.OAWebBeanHelper.processFormRequest(Unknown Source)
at oracle.apps.fnd.framework.webui.OAWebBeanContainerHelper.processFormRequest(Unknown Source)
at oracle.apps.fnd.framework.webui.beans.form.OAFormBean.processFormRequest(Unknown Source)
at oracle.apps.fnd.framework.webui.OAWebBeanHelper.processFormRequestChildren(Unknown Source)
at oracle.apps.fnd.framework.webui.OAWebBeanHelper.processFormRequestChildren(Unknown Source)
at oracle.apps.fnd.framework.webui.OAWebBeanHelper.processFormRequest(Unknown Source)
at oracle.apps.fnd.framework.webui.OAWebBeanContainerHelper.processFormRequest(Unknown Source)
at oracle.apps.fnd.framework.webui.beans.OABodyBean.processFormRequest(Unknown Source)
at oracle.apps.fnd.framework.webui.OAPageBean.processFormRequest(Unknown Source)
at oracle.apps.fnd.framework.webui.OAPageBean.preparePage(Unknown Source)
at oracle.apps.fnd.framework.webui.OAPageBean.preparePage(Unknown Source)
at oracle.apps.fnd.framework.webui.OAPageBean.preparePage(Unknown Source)
at _OA._jspService(_OA.java:75)
at com.orionserver.http.OrionHttpJspPage.service(OrionHttpJspPage.java:59)
at oracle.jsp.runtimev2.JspPageTable.service(JspPageTable.java:473)
at oracle.jsp.runtimev2.JspServlet.internalService(JspServlet.java:594)
at oracle.jsp.runtimev2.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:518)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)
at com.evermind.server.http.ServletRequestDispatcher.invoke(ServletRequestDispatcher.java:734)
at com.evermind.server.http.ServletRequestDispatcher.forwardInternal(ServletRequestDispatcher.java:391)
at com.evermind.server.http.HttpRequestHandler.doProcessRequest(HttpRequestHandler.java:908)
at com.evermind.server.http.HttpRequestHandler.processRequest(HttpRequestHandler.java:458)
at com.evermind.server.http.HttpRequestHandler.serveOneRequest(HttpRequestHandler.java:226)
at com.evermind.server.http.HttpRequestHandler.run(HttpRequestHandler.java:127)
at com.evermind.server.http.HttpRequestHandler.run(HttpRequestHandler.java:116)
at oracle.oc4j.network.ServerSocketReadHandler$SafeRunnable.run(ServerSocketReadHandler.java:260)
at oracle.oc4j.network.ServerSocketAcceptHandler.procClientSocket(ServerSocketAcceptHandler.java:234)
at oracle.oc4j.network.ServerSocketAcceptHandler.access$700(ServerSocketAcceptHandler.java:29)
at oracle.oc4j.network.ServerSocketAcceptHandler$AcceptHandlerHorse.run(ServerSocketAcceptHandler.java:879)
at com.evermind.util.ReleasableResourcePooledExecutor$MyWorker.run(ReleasableResourcePooledExecutor.java:303)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: I don't see that error - ORA-22927: invalid LOB locator specified - in your callstack.  Is that a cut and paste error?  Does the PL/SQL work if you call your function from a SQL session?

Comment: oracle.apps.fnd.framework.OAException: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-
    22927: invalid LOB locator specified   This is the error I got when I run the Impl code from jDeveloper

Comment: ...but does it work from a SQL session?  If it only fails when called from Java I'll look at your AM code.  If it fails from SQL then of course we need to look at your PL/SQL.  Might be an idea to add some debug into both your AM and PL/SQL code so you can see where this falls over.  The last debug message I get is from your controller : FileUploadCO.processFormRequest and this does not help us to locate the problem

Comment: Hi  Christian Palmer, I have updated the CO in the Blog. I'm so new to this jDeveloper environment. just know core java. Trying to catch up the things. My need is to pass the file name and file content as Blob to PLSQL procedure. So that the PLSQL procedure catch the blob and write it into a table.    Help me on this

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer : This is not a complete answer (yet) but it is probably too much to put into a comment.

The core routine is your file_upload() PL/SQL routine - you need to get this working from a SQL session to make sure it works before you start calling it from a java session.  I am pretty sure that file_upload() does not work right now:

UTL_FILE - you are passing a raw directory path as the location parameter.  This is not correct - you should be passing the name of a directory from ALL_DIRECTORIES.  So your first step is to create a row in here for your path :

```
SQL> CREATE DIRECTORY XXTXB_FILE_DIR AS '/u01/Jdevloper/xxtxb';
```

Then when you'll call UTL file with something like :

```
lv_file_handle := 
 UTL_FILE.FOPEN
  ('XXTXB_FILE_DIR'
  ,LV_FILE_NAME
  ,'wb'
  , 32767
  )
;
```

Note this all assumes /u01/Jdevloper/xxtxb is a valid directory.

Once you have the package compiled then you can call it from a SQL session :

```
BEGIN

  XXTXB_UPLOAD_FILE_PKG.FILE_UPLOAD
   (P_FILE_NAME    => 'test.txt'
   ,P_FILE_CONTENT => utl_raw.cast_to_raw('blah')
   )
  ;

END ;
```

If this throws errors then debug here before you start calling the routine from java.  Let me know how you get on...

Comment: Hi Christian. Thanks for your guidelines. I had taken down the thinks as you guided. Now the PLSQL procedure runs fine on SQL session. Now i'm looking into the OAF part will return back to you. Thanks once again Christian....

Comment: Hi Christian after completing the SQL session error now I get some Conversion error. This comment segment is not enough to paste that so I will edit the blog and add the error log atlast.

Comment: OK I don't have much experience with character encoding.  However your PL/SQL does two operations on the BLOB : 1 - insert into a BLOB column 2 - write the BLOB contents to the filesystem.  I would comment one and then the other to see which is causing the problem (it could of course be both)

Comment: Okay Christian Will try the same

Comment: oracle.apps.fnd.framework.OAException: Message not found. Application: FND, Message Name: FND_MESSAGE_NOT_FOUND. Message not found. Application: FND, Message Name: FND_GENERIC_MESSAGE. Tokens: MESSAGE = java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00603: ORACLE server session terminated by fatal error
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [kghfrmrg:nxt], [0x7F6D968B7FB0], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
ORA-24812: character set conversion to or from UCS2 failed
ORA-06512: at "APPS.XXTXB_UPLOAD_FILE_PKG", line 68
ORA-06512: at line 1;            **Can you guide on this Christian**

Comment: have you managed to isolate what is throwing this error - the table insert or writing the data to the filesystem?

Comment: as I said, character encoding is not a specialism of mine.  It seems likely that your java environment is using UCS2 and your database is not (SELECT * FROM nls_database_parameters).  You may need to convert the encoding of your text - this link might help : https://stackoverflow.com/q/10942900/6171686